# How can I prevent a white border from appearing on the first half of my webpage when zooming in?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs in my code- one for the first portion of my page and one for the rest as shown below. The issue is that when I zoom in, the first half of the page has a large white border appear to the right of it, almost as a way for it to be able to resize when I zoom in. This issue does not occur for the second half. I'd also like to add that when I zoom in, the background image stays the exact same, meaning no warping whatsoever. How do I fix this?

```
.firsthalf{
    height: 100vh;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75),rgba(0,0,0,0.75)),url(det.jpg); 
        background-size: cover;   
        background-position: center;
        min-width: 100%;
        overflow-x: hidden  



    

}
.secondhalf{
    background-color: black;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: table;
    height: 4000px;


}
```

As you can see, I have already tried modifying the overflow settings as well as both the min and max width but all my efforts have been to no avail. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Nitro26/full/yLRGVBe)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLyuo.png)

Comment: Not sure I see what you see. Perhaps attach a screenshot to the question.

Comment: whats browser you're experiencing this with?

Comment: It's the secondhalf that has a problem. 
Remove the 'display: table' and both div's are equal width.
The overflow hidden works as intended, it's just the second div that is growing outside your container

Comment: @Joeri Did not work, what's happening now is that both elements have it.

Comment: @alphapilgrim Any browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both div's should be treated the same so don't mix `display: table;` on one div, `overflow hidden;` on an other...
When you change your div's like this you still need to account for the .ib elements you gave a fixed width of 1000px; Change that to `max-width: 1000px;`

```
.firsthalf{
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75),rgba(0,0,0,0.75)),url(det.jpg); 
  background-size: cover;   
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden  
}
.secondhalf{
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4000px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```